# Как захостить приложение на rasbperry pi?

Tags: python, ubuntu, сеть, raspberry-pi

Очень хочется захостить приложение с графическим интерфейсом, написанное на питоне, на малинке, стоящей у меня в комнате, чтобы хоть кто извне мог воспользоваться интерфейсом (программа парсит логи и предоставляет это в читабельном виде). Так же хочется почитать про технологии и реализацию подробнее, но я даже не знаю с чего начать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057675/pyinstaller-no-predefined-compiler-for-raspberry-pi

Comment: Кажется что это полезная ссылка, но я не понимаю как ее применить

Comment: Ну значит поставил как там написано pyinstaller. И дальше собрал свой прожект `pyinstaller your_main.py`

Comment: OHO?11 символов нужно...

Comment: Нужно уточнить в чем собственно вопрос. Программа уже есть и проблема с тем, чтобы ее сделать доступной? Или программы еще нет?

Comment: Я ваш вопрос не очень понял к сожалению. Ежели вы имели ввиду типа сайт, то apache/ngnix...

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/nginx.md

Comment: Программа в активной разработке. Хочу чтобы любой вбил ip адрес и мог воспользоваться интерфейсом программы

Comment: *мог воспользоваться интерфейсом программы* — используя какой протокол?